# Kubernetes pod terminating option?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, argocd

Now, I use Argo CD to deploy in AWS EKS.
Usually, when the pods is in the Running state, the existing pods is terminated.

But I want to shut down the pods after **the application of the pod runs perfectly**,

Is there any way?

Comment: You should deploy your service as a Job - https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/job/ -- With that, the pod will be terminated after the application runs.

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure what configuration are you using with ArgoCD for your CI/CD process. But it is recommended to use readiness and liveness probs [link](https://thenewstack.io/kubernetes-health-checks-using-probes/#:%7E:text=To%20check%20the%20status%20of,ready%20to%20accept%20user%20traffic.) to determine the lifecycle of the pod.

For example, Kubernetes uses the readiness prob to allow actual traffic from the service to be directed to the pod when running rollingUpdates

Potentially when using vanilla Kubernetes deployment with the readiness and liveness probs. A pod would terminate only when another pod is actually ready to accept traffic. i.e its readiness and liveness probs passed the relevant threshold.

ArgoCD has their own [alternatives](https://www.patrickdap.com/post/argocd-health-checks/) and health checks which you can customize